# Google CDN for jquery widgets

Tags: jquery-ui, google-cdn

Do you know if jquery widgets such as "slider" or "button" are available for download in the Google CDN?

I only found "datepicker" available in the manifest so far :
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.1/MANIFEST

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Google CDN includes the complete jQuery UI suite in [one file](https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.js).

You're seeing the internationalization (i18n) files that allow you to display the date picker in multiple languages.